# Count hyperlinks in power bi

Tags: powerbi, text-mining, counting, columnsorting, text-manipulation

I have a column named "body" and in this columns there many rows that contain hyperlinks in text.
[image]

is it possible in power bi **to count if there is a hyperlink in text then create a new column that shows the number of hyperlink provided in the text** or **atleast show in a different column that this text contain hyperlinks.** TA

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `Custom Column` to count the number of occurrences of `<a`  (note there is a space after `a`) in the body. You can do that using [`Text.PositionOf`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/text-positionof) function by passing `Occurrence.All` parameter, so the formula used to create the column should be something like this:

```
= List.Count(Text.PositionOf([body], "<a ", Occurrence.All))
```

This will give you how many times `<a`  appears in the body (which is the number of hyperlinks):

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot that really worked. I want to ask another queston related to this. if i want to count multiple values occurences in a text like "<a " and "https:", how can i do that?

Comment: Sum up the results of two separate List.Count - `= List.Count(Text.PositionOf([body], "<a ", Occurrence.All)) + List.Count(Text.PositionOf([body], "https:", Occurrence.All))`